# Odoo enterprises edition

Tags: odoo

I tried to pass the value from one pop up model to another model using odoo server action but I could not pass the value.
How to pass string field from one popup model to another model with button click?
Please anybody help me

Comment: I'm not familiar with odoo but in general, when you ask a question, you need to give more details about your context, what you are trying to do, what you tried, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be more specific?
To me this seems simple.

1. get record from model1: `self.env['model1name'].search([('name', '=', record1name)])`
2. get record from model2: `self.env['model2name'].search([('name', '=', record2name)])`
3. do `model2_rec.write({'fieldname': model1_rec.fieldname})`